# problem with 'std::for_each', does not map function over vector as expected

Tags: c++

I'm starting to play with c++ recently, and I'm coming from functional land so you can imagine my relief when I discovered the for_each function and then my frustration when I discovered I can't make it do what I want. What I want to achieve can be done with a simple for loop, but I seem to have developed an allergy. Anyway, some things work: For example:

```
int main () {

std::vector<std::string> numbers {"-1.2","2.2","3.3","4.4","5.5"};

std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](std::string& i) {
  std::stof(i);
});

for(auto num : numbers) {
  std::cout << num << "\n";
}

return 0;
}
```

seems to work. But this does not:

```
vector<float> f(vector<string> numbers) {

std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), [](std::string& i) {
   std::stof(i);
});

return numbers;
}

std::vector<std::string> numbers {"-1.2","2.2","3.3","4.4","5.5"};
f(numbers);
```

The compiler tells me he has trouble converting basic_string  to vector in this case, which I can't understand since that is what the stof is supposed to do. Initially I thought I was suppose to bind another vector to the for each like this:

```
vector<float> actualnumbers = std::for_each( numbers.begin(), numbers.end()
                                           , [](std::string& i) {std::stof(i);});
```

and then return that, but that didn't seem to work either. Can someone enlighten me? What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Other things I have tried are writing my own map function:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
vector<T> map (T (*f)(U), vector<U> vec) {
  vector<T> out;
  for (auto v : vec)
  {
  out.push_back((*f)(v));
  };
  return out;
};
```

This one actually works as long as you don't try to feed it a lambda function, I'm not sure why there should be a difference between lambda functions and any other ones? But it also feels like a hack, isn't this pretty much what I should be able to do with for_each?

Comment: `numbers` is a `vector<string>` - you cannot change its type at runtime. You need to create a `vector<float>` and fill your converted values into that so you can return it

Comment: Also you are completely ignoring the return value of `std::stof`, making your lambda pretty useless

Comment: Your calls to `std::for_each` don't do anything. `std::stof` *returns* the result of the conversion, and you discard it. Besides, C++ is statically typed: once you write `std::vector<std::string> numbers`, `numbers` can only be a `vector<string>`, not `vector<float>` or something else.

Comment: Regarding your P.S., a function pointer has no space to store lambda captures. It points to a function, that's it (including a lambda with no captures because that's just a function with syntax around it).

Comment: You're passing a copy of vector with `vector<float> f(vector<string> numbers)`, instead you should've write `vector<float> f(vector<string> &numbers)`.

Comment: @adem Should be a `const` reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::for_each` applies a function returning `void` to each of the elements of the collection--since `std::stof` is a pure function, you're silently performing a no-op. In particular, you are *not* converting the elements of the vector in place. The correct way to do this is to use `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<std::string> numbers {"-1.2","2.2","3.3","4.4","5.5"};
std::vector<float> floats;
std::transform(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::back_inserter(floats),
               [](const std::string& i) { return std::stof(i); }));

std::for_each(floats.begin(), floats.end(), [](float i) {
   std::cout << i << ", ";
});
```

Comment: Great thanks, this clears up things quite a bit. So for_each on it's own doesn't return anything, it just applies the function sequentially and its up to me to organise what they return, if I like, or I should just use transform like you suggest.

Comment: @Orbit for_each doesn't return anything. Functionally speaking, it's really used for only the side effects of the lambda that's passed.